# How do programs check if the user is root

Tags: root, system-administration

Some programs behave differently based on if the user that runs it is root. For example, the -h option of sshd.

Usually, how do they do that? As far as I know, root is not a special user, but just have more permissions. So do they check if the user is root by username, or UID, or what?

Thanks

Comment: By checking if the uid is zero.